# How to call get method of one contract from another?

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-invocation

I want to call a method of a contract from another contract. I've already read this post:
[calling one contract to another contract method](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45277/calling-one-contract-to-another-contract-method), but it doesn't work for me.

When I create the caller and try to execute the Set() method it perfectly works, but if call the Get() it alwayas returns '0'.

Can someone help me?

These are my simple code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;


contract callee{

    uint public x;

    constructor() public
    {
        x = 1;
    }

    function set (uint k) public
    {
        x = k;
    }

    function get () public view returns (uint)
    {
        return x;
    }

}

contract caller{

    callee c;

    constructor() public
    {
        c = new callee();
    }

    function get() public view returns (uint k)
    {
        return c.get();
    }

    function set(uint k) public
    {
        c.set(k);
    }

    function get_calle() public view returns (callee)
    {
        return c;
    }


}
```

I'm using Web3 Provider and Remix to test.

I have tried to call get() from the callee after getting its location, and it returns the right value, so the set() methods works. Why can't I use get() from the caller?

[image: methods invocation from remix using Web3]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `callee` you created isn't the one the `caller` is interacting with. It's creating a new one.

Replace

```
c = new callee();
```

with

```
c = callee(0xabcdef);
```

But instead of `0xabcdef` put in the address of the deployed `callee` contract.

Comment: That's not the point. I want to create a new callee and edit its state. I just deploy the caller contract wich create the callee and then execute the get after the set. As u can see in the image, I'm working on the same callee, but the get() of the caller returns 0 while the get() of the callee returns 10.

Comment: Ah I understand, my bad. I tested it using Remix, with Injected Web3 on Rinkeby and got the same problem. Could `set` from `caller` but only got accurate `get` result from `callee`. But when I copied the address of `caller`, removed `caller` and reopened an instance at that address, `get` seems to work. Do you get the same result?

Comment: I tried, but i always get 0

Comment: It's odd, it may be a bug with Remix because as I said, it works for me when I re-launch the caller, and I don't see any issue with your Solidity code.

Comment: Ok thank you! What should i try?

Comment: If it is a problem with Remix, you could try a different browser, or go to the support tab and ask for help there.

Comment: I tried only using geth (defining the ABI, mining the contract and calling the method) but the result is always 0. If i test in JavaScript VM it works perfectly, where the problem can be ? I really need your help please!