# Sending request message to a specific wallet address

Tags: message

I want to send an information message or request (eg, request for approval , or request for funds)  from my contract to a specific ETH wallet address. How can I do this ?

Comment: You just the encode the string message as a hexadecimal value and you set it as the call data.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a message in the calldata of an transaction by using the [`.call`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=.call#address-related) function.

Example (Solidity):

```
contract Contract {
    function sendMessage(string memory _message, address _receiver) external {
        _receiver.call(abi.encode(_message));
    }
}
```

Or with the [sendTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction) function in Web3. Paste the message in the data field. First convert the message to hexadecimals.

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
     from: "yourAddress",
     to: "receiverAddress",
     value: "0", 
     data: "0x48656c6c6f20746865726521"
}); // Sends the message 'Hello there!'
```

Comment: Thanks for this , I will try it out... is it possible to request a response (eg, Yes or No) via the message ?

Comment: If the smart contract you are sending the message to has a external/ public function that returns yes/ no (true/ false), then it is possible. This can be achieved by calling this function from your contract. [Tutorial](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/45279/51404)